# dynamic and stack memory allocation done by the compiler?

Tags: c, memory-management

I know there are several types of memory allocation. Taking C as language example, we have static allocation, stack allocation, heap allocation.

I understand that the static allocation is done by compiler, but the other two takes place on run time. Who is responsible for that, is it the Compiler, Process or the Operating System?

I'm basically asking if the compiler is involved in running a program?

Comment: Heap allocation is done by specific functions: [malloc, realloc, calloc](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc)... so the coder is responsible for allocation and for release (`free`) the memory. Stack it is done at runtime, by assembler code generated by compiler at compile time.

Comment: The compiler is not involved in any way when the program is running.

Comment: @LPs: you are right, post it as an answer !!!

Comment: @LPs , the assembler coder meaning the OS? 
and i know that the coder is responsible for heap allocation , my question is: do the compiler in any way involved during run time?

Comment: There is neither a heap nor a stack mandated by the C language. They are implementation details and alternative approaches can be used (and are used).

Comment: _Compiler_ and _runtime_ are incompatible words. I mean that the compiling step is something done before you have something to execute.

Comment: @Destructor thanks, but an answer to this question must be more detailed and must be explained more in depth which takes time I haven't right now. ;)

Comment: About the stack, it depends on the OS you are using. As an High overview you can assume that he OS that starts the program gives to it a memory space called stack where that the program can use to allocate function local  scoped variables, if no `static`. _do the compiler in any way involved during run time?_ simple answer is: no, it isn't.

Comment: LPs Thanks. 

@Olaf can you explain it deeper and with more detail because i failed to understand the variety of answers given.

i will try to explain better:

each process have Code,Data ,Stack : the global var' are in Data,and the heap is also there, and there is stack .

my question is : during run time of program who is responsible for allocating and managing the memory stack,heap ? who allocate new memory and update the SP ? who update the heap size? 

the process ? the OS?

Comment: Small answer, Olaf will give you a detailed one I think. Who change SP: CPU, MCU or whatever is in charge to manage it. Mostly you have MSP (Main Stack Pointer) and PSP (Process Stack Pointer). Heap size is not managed but it is, mainly, pre allocated by OS. Heap is managed, as already commented, by specific function that make all the actions. The whole heap, mainly, is allocated for the process by OS. You should also think about small system without OS, so linker scripts helps to define those sections.

Comment: @LPs: It is actually more a matter of the Processor used. The OS managing it follows from the requirements/capabilities of the hardware.

Comment: I will not give a comprehensive answer, as that is not the place nor the site. Read the C standard (maybe start with a good book) to get a gasp on what the standard mandates and what not. Then some processor (CPU, DSP, etc.) reference manuals and some compiler manuals, too (for some CPUs there might even be different approaches) to learn which alternatives there are. Just takes some years to master (whihc is the reason I will not further discuss this).

Comment: To add: it completely depends on the target who allocates what. There can be a scenario where the compiler allocates all, the linker, an OS, a run-time. Or a mixture thereof. (Yes, I know this leaves you not better informed, but maybe a bit wiser).

Comment: @Olaf and LPs , thank you for your quick and detailed answers.
it was very informative and helpful

Answer (score 4):

OS is responsible for stack and heap memory allocation.

The OS allocate stack memory for every thread and the language runtime calls the OS for allocate heap memory.

Comment: Most C programs run on systems without a full-grown OS. And quite some don't even have a stack for variables.

Comment: I would say this depends, really. The full answer should include various scenarios, explaining hardware differences, libc for barebones (like avr-libc) or linux, etc. I agree with @Olaf - it is wrong to assume that *all* the hardware runs OS, yet the source code might use dynamic allocation. Here, malloc without OS: http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/malloc.html

Answer (score -1):

Compiler is not involved in running a program. Its job is to build the program to a stage from where the linker can take it to create an executable or take to a engine that executes the code in case of a dynamic builder. It only checks for some protocols that have to be followed for a particular language.

Static allocation (storage space) depends on the files that are being linked to and the storage required by the static structures and variables in the code.

Dynamic allocation is taken by the memory management unit where the resources are been allocated to the task that is in the memory and that is where the heap allocation takes place during the runtime.